# Gallai--Milgram theorem: relation between path cover number and independence number?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Gallai--Milgram theorem states that for any directed graph $D$, there exists a family of vertex-disjoint paths $P_1,\dots, P_k$ such that $\cup_{i=1}^nV(P_i)=V(D)$ and there exists an independent set $\{v_1,\dots, v_k\}$ such that $v_i\in V(P_i)$ for all $i$.

It implies that the independence number (size of a maximum independent set) is at least the path covering number (minimum number of disjoint paths required to cover all the vertices).

I am wondering is the other direction is true, i.e., the path covering number is at least the independence number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A clear counterexample is taking $D$ to be an $n$-vertex directed path graph. This has path covering number $1$, but independence number $\lceil \frac n2\rceil$.

If we want two equal quantities, we can define the *path subcovering number* of $D$ (a term I just made up) to be the maximum path covering number of any induced subgraph of $D$.

Then for a directed graph $D$ with independence number $k$:

- If any induced subgraph of $D$ has path covering number $k'$, then it also has independence number at least $k'$. But an independent set in an induced subgraph is also an independent set in $D$, so $k' \le k$; therefore $k$ is also an upper bound on the path subcovering number.
- On the other hand, a $k$-vertex independent set is an induced subgraph of $D$ that takes $k$ paths to cover (each path will have length $0$). So $k$ is a lower bound on the path subcovering number.

Therefore the path subcovering number of $D$ is exactly equal to the independence number of $D$.